# Reading XML by LIBXML2 issue

Tags: c, xml

When i tried to read xml by c program i use `libxml2`.
but i am facing error in `xmlparsefile`
is there any problem with predefined function `xmlparsefile`?

```
xmlDocPtr doc;
xmlNodePtr cur;
doc = xmlParseFile("sample.xml");//here doc cannot read anything..
if (doc == NULL ) 
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Document not parsed successfully. \n");
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    return;
}
cur = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);//Unhandled Exception occurs
```

Could anyone please help to solve this issue?

Comment: You are actually using C++ and the #import directive.  The XxxPtr types are auto-generated smart pointer types whose methods translate any HRESULT error code to a `_com_error` exception.  Use try/catch to catch it.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/com-error-class

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a backquote before `xmlDocPtr` ? However, giving it absolute path of the file should fix the problem.
Say you have the file `sample.txt` in `/home/Desktop/MyDocsSample/sample.txt`, then you should give the parser the absolute path.

## EDIT

[The link I told you in the comment](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/xml/2004-May/msg00202.html)
He seem to have your same issue

## Edit 2

[msvcrt.dll and msvcp60.dll](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24417)
If you didn't have these dlls course your installation crashed

Comment: the xmlparsefile function will not parse the parse it returns nothing to doc.

Comment: then doc has cxx0030 error:expression not evaluated after this line doc=xmlparsefile("myfile.xml")

Comment: @MuthuSelvam The xml file is fornatted correctly, isn't it, Otherwise the xmlparsefile should return null

Comment: @MuthuSelvam the function simply crashes. Try to install the latest version . Alternatively, if the crash does  not let you continue the program, try to redirect the stderr to /dev/null . Here is a link that might help you

Comment: could you please tell me version what i have to install.. are you talking about the whole libxml2 package..if yes please provide me the link

Comment: @MuthuSelvam Linux,Mac,Windows and version?

Comment: @MuthuSelvam Whatever, if you have git do    git clone git://git.gnome.org/libxml2 , else check out this: http://xmlsoft.org/downloads.html

Comment: i download libxml from your link but when try to build the file .lib or dll is needed..where can i found that

Comment: @MuthuSelvam here you re

Comment: what are trying to convey??

Comment: @MuthuSelvam Actually I think these are the only third party dlls lixml2 need, otherwise tell me what dll you miss. You are on windows right?

Comment: I'm in windows.i download all files related to libxml but i cant link it with my project.bcaz i dont have lib file or dll.i tried to compile libxml it also showing lots of errors

Comment: @MuthuSelvam have you tried installing that one i post the link under edit 2?